# css nth-last-child(odd) sombrear pares e impares

Tags: html, css

Hola estos intentando sombrear una tabla, en las filas pares e impares, pero sombrea todas las filas por igual.

El código CSS es el siguiente:

```
.tablecuando {
   width: 70%;
   margin-left: 10px; 
   margin-right: auto;
   background:none;
   float: left;
   clear:left;
    }

.tablecuando table {
   width: 70%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   border: 0px solid #000;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   caption-side: top;
}

.tablecuando tr td:nth-last-child(odd) {
  background-color: #E3FBFB;
}

.tablecuando tr td:nth-last-child(even) {
  background-color:white;
}

.tablecuando caption {
   width: auto;
   padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
   vertical-align: midle;
   font-size: 12px;
   border: 0px solid Black;
   color: #0000FF;
    Background: #EB8921;
   /*Background: #F0F8FF;*/
}

.tablecuando table tr {
   font-family: Calibri, Arial;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: midle;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 1px;
   color:Black;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:12px;
}

.tablecuando table th {
   font-family: Calibri, Arial, Bold;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: midle;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 1px;
   color:#0000FF;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:12px;
   background: #EB8921;
}

.tablecuando table td {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: midle;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 0.3em;
   color:green;
   font-size:12px;
}
```

y el codigo de la tabla es :

```
<div class="tablecuando" >

  <table class="table" >

<?php if($user_language=='en' or $user_language=='en-US'){ ?>

    <caption>
                    <div style=" text-align: center; color:#00008B;"><?php echo "<b> List of Horses</b><br/> ";?>
                    <div style=" text-align: center; color:#00008B;"><?php echo "<b> Touch the Name and you will see the Race</b><br/>";?>
        </caption>
    <thead>

            <tr>
                    <th width="15%">Name</th>
            </tr>

    </thead>

<?php }
        else
        {   ?>

        <caption>
                    <div style=" text-align: center; color:#00008B;"><?php echo "<b> Listado de SPC</b><br/> ";?>
                    <div style=" text-align: center; color:#00008B;"><?php echo "<b> Toque el Nombre y verá la Carrera</b><br/>";?>
        </caption>
    <thead>

            <tr>
                    <th width="15%">Nombre</th>
            </tr>

    </thead>

<?php   }

if ($Cont1 > 3) {   include('buscarcabanom.php');       }
            else
                {   include('buscarcabanomex.php'); }




// echo "<font color=yellow> Cantidad:  $z </font>";    

for ($i = 0; $i < $z; $i++)
{

// echo "<font color=yellow> Fecha:  $FechaNac[$i] </font>";    

$FechaNac[$i]   =   explode("-", $FechaNac[$i]);

$Ano[$i]    =   $FechaNac[$i][0];   

// echo "<font color=yellow> Ano:   $Ano[$i] </font> <br/>";

?>

    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <a class="cabaprog" href="webresultados3.php?idcab=<?php echo $idcab[$i] ;?>&orden=1&idi=<?php echo $user_language ;?>" >     
                        <?php if ($ExNombre[$i] == "") { echo "$nomcaba[$i] - $Ano[$i]"; }
                     else { echo "$nomcaba[$i] (ex $ExNombre[$i]) - $Ano[$i]";   }?></a></td>
<?php
}
?>

            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Yo estoy comenzando a hacer esto de las tablas, me gustaría que me puedan guiar

Los Datos que se publican en cada Fila se obtienen de una base de datos MYSQL

Ese sombreado me funciona en algunas tablas y otras no.

Y las estructuras de las tablas son similares, solo cambian la cantidad de columnas

No llego a comprender lo que pasa

Muchas Gracias

---

Puse esto :

```
<style>
        .cuerpo .celda:nth-of-type(odd) {
          background-color: #E3FBFB;
        }
        .cuerpo .celda:nth-child(even) {
          background-color:white;
        }
</style>

</head>
```

y en la Tabla esto:

```
    <tbody Class="cuerpo">
            <tr Class="celda">
                <td >
                    <a class="cabaprog" href="webresultados3.php?idcab=<?php echo $idcab[$i] ;?>&orden=1&idi=<?php echo $user_language ;?>" >     
                        <?php if ($ExNombre[$i] == "") { echo "$nomcaba[$i] - $Ano[$i]"; }
                     else { echo "$nomcaba[$i] (ex $ExNombre[$i]) - $Ano[$i]";   }?></a></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

el css lo dejé así:

```
.tablecuando {
   width: 70%;
   margin-left: 10px; 
   margin-right: auto;
   background:none;
   float: left;
   clear:left;
    }

.tablecuando table {
   width: 70%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   border: 0px solid #000;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   caption-side: top;
}

.tablecuando caption {
   width: auto;
   padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
   vertical-align: midle;
   font-size: 12px;
   border: 0px solid Black;
   color: #0000FF;
    Background: #EB8921;
   /*Background: #F0F8FF;*/
}

.tablecuando table th {
   font-family: Calibri, Arial, Bold;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: midle;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 1px;
   color:#0000FF;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:12px;
   background: #EB8921;
}
```

y no me funciona, se ve así:

[image: Vision de la Tabla]

Comment: solo debes cambiar `nth-last-child(odd)` por `nth-child(odd)`

Comment: Disculpe, es que seguí haciendo pruebas, poniendolo como Ud. dice el resultado es el mismo

Comment: Y se que funciona como Ud. dice. Lo que no puedo descubrir es porque no funciona en mi caso

Comment: simplemente tienes que limpiar el navegador o ejecutarlo en modo incognito y veras!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pseudoclase `last-child` solo es para seleccionar el último elemento.

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      a:last-child {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <section class="enlaces">
      <a href="" class="enlace">Enlace mio Uno</a>
      <a href="" class="enlace">Enlace mio Dos</a>
      <a href="" class="enlace">Enlace mio Tres</a>
    </section>
```

Si tu deseas elegir tanto las filas pares como así las impares entonces debes de cambiar por el uso de la pseudoclase `nth-child()` la cual podemos usar para seleccionar uno o mas elementos en función de la *condición de selección* que pasemos como argumento a dicha función.

**Ejemplo**

```html
      <style>
        .cuerpo .celda:nth-child(odd) {
          color: red;
        }
        .cuerpo .celda:nth-child(even) {
          color: blue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="listados">
      <thead class="encabezado">
        <tr>
          <th>Encabezado Uno</th>
          <th>Encabezado Dos</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="cuerpo">
        <tr class="celda">
          <td>Valor 1</td>
          <td>Valor 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="celda">
          <td>Valor 2</td>
          <td>Valor 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="celda">
          <td>Valor 3</td>
          <td>Valor 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="celda">
          <td>Valor 3</td>
          <td>Valor 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Referencias**

- [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)